# How to switch on spring project to maven

Tags: spring, maven

I want to switch my java spring project to maven and start from simple srtucture. I have created archetype project and add subfolder with Service.java in main package. I describe dependencies but get an error:

maven Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring:jar:3.1.1 i  central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.home.springtraining</groupId><artifactId>SpringTrainingTemplate</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>SpringTrainingTemplate</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do you know why I can not dowload this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version and artifact ID are wrong, they should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that since (AFAIR) Spring 3.0 there is no longer singel `spring.jar` - you must include `spring-core.jar`, `spring-context.jar`, `spring-beans.jar` and whatever you also need. You can find all of them in [maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/).

Comment: Thanks! It helps. Could you please share a link where I could read about particular qualities in details? The cause of errors as this is difficult to spot for new maven adepts.

Comment: @WinteWinte: what do you mean by "*particular qualities*"? I'd be happy to help further, I just don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I mean the information that describes how I should format pom file. Of course I have read the official guide but it is not enough for dependecies as this

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the 3.x release series Spring is not distributed as a single, all-including jar. You need to include the sub-libraries you actually need. You can get an idea of what is available in the Maven Central repository [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework).